# How to preserve NetCDF dimensions with gdal.warp

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, netcdf

I have a netcdf file that is structured with precipitation grid values with dimensions (time, x, y)

When I perform gdal.warp (in python if that matters) I get a new file that has multiple bands that have dimensions (x, y), with the number of bands = len(time) of the previous file and time is not part of the new file.

Is there a way to preserve the dimensions, precipitation name, and time in the new file?

```
import gdal

warped = gdal.Warp(
                destNameOrDestDS=destNameOrDestDS,
                srcDSOrSrcDSTab=srcDSOrSrcDSTab,
                srcSRS=srcSRS,
                dstSRS=dstSRS,
                dstNodata=float(srcNodata),
                format="NETCDF",
                xRes=xRes,
                yRes=yRes,
                targetAlignedPixels=targetAlignedPixels,
            )
```

So my source netcdf file looks like:

- crs
- QPE
- time
- x
- y
- z

where crs is the coordinate system and QPE is precipitation and then my output looks like:

- Albers
- Band1
- Band2
- Band3
- x
- y

I would like to preserve the original structure so combine the Bands into a single 3 dimensional array with time as the 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetCDF driver is documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/netcdf.html

> **Creation Issues**
>
> This driver supports creation of NetCDF file following the CF-1
>   convention. You may create set of 2D datasets. Each variable array is
>   named Band1, Band2, … BandN. Each band will have metadata tied to it
>   giving a short description of the data it contains.

Is seems that you must use some other tool than GDAL for creating a 3D dataset.

Comment: I figured that since I found a 5 year old open issue on it, before migrating to github.

Comment: @JeffTilton hi, could you shared the solution? Probably could solve mu problem: I have thousand tiff file and need to convert it to netcdf with time dimension enabled and merge into single netcdf.

Comment: @user97103 you probably wouldn't like my solution, but you can see what I did [here](https://github.com/jetilton/nwrfc-grids/blob/master/Grids/Grids.py) at the end of the `warp` method.  I since learned of the [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package for xarray that uses gdal on the backend.  It has a warp method, but I couldn't get it to work, although I didn't try hard since I had this set.  I think that would be the better route.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your data in .tiff with `gdal_translate`, make the resize with `gdalwarp`, and then back to .nc with `gdal_translate` again.

Tips for increased speed: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalWarp